Looking for a movie where a woman and some knights walk down a sunlit hallway?
I'd like to know the name of the movie pictured in this video (at the time I've linked to). The one with the lady in front and knight-soldiers behind.
The short scene shows a medieval setting in some sort of castle with a woman in expensive clothes (possibly a queen). She is walking down a sunlight hallway, accompanied by several men with swords.

Please don't post questions solely consisting of a link. Links expire. At least add description of the link content, in this case the movie you are searching for. This might help other people as well who search for this movie.

I'm sorry but I don't know anything about the movie except the short scene of it's trailer in the video. How am I supposed to describe the movie?

Describe what the scene shows (after all that scene is what caught your attention). Additionally (also not exclusively) to that you could post a screenshot. Identify questions are not a good fit for the SE format anyway, but if you add a description at least there is a chance this helps someone else looking for the same movie. In the current state, if the youtube video should go down, the question is worthless to anyone else.

I took the freedom to add a short description. Feel free to improve it.

  
The lady in the front is Eleanor Tomlinson, who plays Princess Isabelle in Jack the Giant Slayer.
[Watch the trailer]
